# Detect if there is any object between two objects with BoxCastAll

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry

I ran into an issue with box-casts while developing a 3D game for mobile.

I want to check the path between my player and his target, to avoid him passing through environmental objects (he doesn't have a rigidbody attached and movement is only possible between specific points).

This is the code that I used to check:

```
private bool CheckPath (Vector3 position, Vector3 target)
{
    Vector3 center = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, target, 0.5f);
    Vector3 halfExtents = new Vector3(1, 1, (transform.position - target).magnitude) / 2;
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation((transform.position - target).normalized);

    RaycastHit[] rhit = Physics.BoxCastAll(center, halfExtents, (transform.position - target).normalized, rotation);
    bool result = rhit.All(r => r.collider.tag != "Environment");

    DebugUtilities.BoxCastDebug.DrawBox(center, halfExtents, rotation, result ? Color.green : Color.red, 3);

    return result;
}
```

This code works for the most situations:

[image]

But fails, for example for this situation:

[image]

To visualize the box-cast I used the script from [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1156087/how-can-you-visualize-a-boxcast-boxcheck-etc.html) Unity Answers link.

I am not sure where the problem lies, although the most likely cause would be a flaw in the debugging script mentioned above, which made me believe that my box-cast call was correct.

I am grateful for every solution, although a simple one would be more appreciated.

*Some further information (if needed):*

- *The objects that I want to make impassable are marked with a `Environment` tag.*
- *I was not the one that wrote the debugging script, it seemed to work at first, so I was fine with it.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three problems in your code

**1**.The `position` variable from the unction parameter is not used. You are instead using `transform.position` which means that the starting point may be wrong.

Replace all your `transform.position` with `position`.

**2**.You are performing the raycast backwards. It should not be `transform.position - target`. That should be `target - transform.position`.

**3**.Your `Physics.BoxCastAll` will not work properly since there is no ending to the raycast. Objects behind the starting will be detected by the raycast. Now, if you fix problem **#2**, the problem will reverse. Now, all the objects in behind the target will also be detected since you did not provide the raycast distance. You can provide the distance with `Vector3.Distance(position, target)` in the last parameter of the `Physics.BoxCastAll` function.

Fixed function:

```
private bool CheckPath(Vector3 position, Vector3 target)
{
    Vector3 halfExtents = Vector3.one;

    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(target - position);
    Vector3 direction = target - position;
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(position, target);

    RaycastHit[] rhit = Physics.BoxCastAll(position, halfExtents, direction, rotation, distance);
    bool result = rhit.All(r => r.collider.tag != "Environment");

    Vector3 center = Vector3.Lerp(position, target, 0.5f);
    halfExtents = new Vector3(1, 1, (target - position).magnitude) / 2;
    DebugUtilities.DrawBox(center, halfExtents, rotation, result ? Color.green : Color.red);
    // Debug.DrawRay(position, direction, result ? Color.green : Color.red);
    return result;
}
```

It's worth setting up 3 objects (Cubes) in order to easily test this function. The first one is from Object (Player). The middle one should be the obstacle with the *"Environment"* tag. The last one should be the target Object where player is moving to.

[image]

Then you can use the script below to test it. Run it and move the obstacle away between the player and the target and it should work as expected.

```
public GameObject playerObject;
public GameObject targetObject;

void Update()
{
    Debug.Log("Path cleared: " + CheckPath(playerObject.transform.position, targetObject.transform.position));
}
```

You will get the similar result below:

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm now, thanks! You got me to finally understand the box-cast call. :)

Comment: No problem. Changed the title to be more useful to future people that search for this problem

Comment: Just to be sure, should `halfExtents` be `Vector3.one / 2`, if I have a unit-sized player?

Comment: `halfExtents` that is passed to `Physics.BoxCastAll` should be the `collidersize/2`. Unfortunately, your function did not have any collider inside it si I used `Vector3.one` which works fine. It it doesn't use the half size of your collider instead. Just get the size and divide it by 2. The `collidersize` that is passed to `DebugUtilities.DrawBox` is totally different and should be left unchanged.