# How to place a temporary object and have it detected by my A* pathfinding algorithm

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a functioning A* path finding algorithm and I'm not trying to place an object, have it picked up by the path finding algorithm and then deleted if it blocks the path. The code I have so far is as follows:

```
if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
{
    Vector3 testPos = new Vector3(hit.transform.position.x, hit.transform.position.y, hit.transform.position.z - 0.633f);
    if (pathFinding.TestLocation(startPos, endPos, wall, testPos))
    {
        Instantiate(wall, testPos, wall.transform.rotation);
     }

  //In the path finding algorithm class
  public bool TestLocation(Vector3 startPos, Vector3 endPos, GameObject wall, Vector3 position)
  {
    GameObject clone = Instantiate(wall, position, wall.transform.rotation);

    if (FindPath(startPos, endPos))
    {
        Debug.Log(FindPath(startPos, endPos));
        Destroy(clone);
        return true;
    } else
    {
        Destroy(clone);
        return false;
    }
}
```

My code doesn't block the object from being built when its bound to block the path, but does block objects being built once the path is blocked which isn't what I intended. I'm stumped as to what's causing this and any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
public bool FindPath (Vector3 startPointValue, Vector3 endPointValue) {
    Vector3 startPosition = new Vector3(startPointValue.x+2.5f, startPointValue.y+0.5f, 0);
    Vector3 endPosition = new Vector3(endPointValue.x+4, endPointValue.y+1, 0);

    Node startNode = grid.NodePosition(startPosition);
    Node endNode = grid.NodePosition(endPosition);

    List<Node> possiblePaths = new List<Node>();
    HashSet<Node> triedPaths = new HashSet<Node>();
    possiblePaths.Add(startNode);

    while(possiblePaths.Count > 0)
    {
        Node currentNode = possiblePaths[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < possiblePaths.Count; i++)
        {
            if (possiblePaths[i].FCost < currentNode.FCost || possiblePaths[i].FCost == currentNode.FCost && possiblePaths[i].hCost < currentNode.hCost)
            {
                currentNode = possiblePaths[i];
            }
        }

        possiblePaths.Remove(currentNode);
        triedPaths.Add(currentNode);


        if (currentNode == endNode)
        {
            RetracePath(startNode, endNode);
            //return true;
        } /*else if (possiblePaths.Count == 0 && !triedPaths.Contains(endNode))
        {
            Debug.Log("Impossible");
            RetracePath(startNode, currentNode);
        }*/

        foreach (Node neighbour in grid.GetNeighbours(currentNode))
        {
            if (!neighbour.blocked || triedPaths.Contains(neighbour))
            {
                continue;
            }

            int newMovementCostToNeighbour = currentNode.gCost + GetDistance(currentNode, neighbour);
            if (newMovementCostToNeighbour<neighbour.gCost || !possiblePaths.Contains(neighbour))
            {
                //Debug.Log(newMovementCostToNeighbour);
                neighbour.gCost = newMovementCostToNeighbour;
                neighbour.hCost = GetDistance(neighbour, endNode);

                neighbour.parent = currentNode;

                if (!possiblePaths.Contains(neighbour))
                {
                    possiblePaths.Add(neighbour);
                }
            }
        }
        if (possiblePaths.Count == 0 && !triedPaths.Contains(endNode))
        {
            //RetracePath(startNode, possiblePaths);
            Debug.Log("is false");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Deleting questions and reasking the same thing again is normally not a good idea.

Comment: My previous question was closed because it was a duplicate with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47372172/detect-if-there-is-any-object-between-two-objects-with-boxcastall, and im not entirely sure how its the same question

Comment: @InBetween can I have some insight into how I'm supposed to ask this question?

Comment: Your question is fine, reposting it isn't. If it gets closed because its marked as a duplicate and you don't agree with the decision, try contacting with whoever closed it or a moderator and explain why you don't consider it being a duplicate. You either convince the person to reopen the question or he convinces you why it is in fact a duplicate. Seems like a win win situation.

Comment: Alright that makes sense, I was under the impression questions deemed "useless" were encouraged to be deleted. Is there anyway to reopen my original question and contact the person who closed it?

Answer (score 1):

> `yield return new WaitUntil(IsBlocked);`

Oh god no. Coroutines are *not* the appropriate tool here, especially with how you've implemented it.  This is what will happen:

1. Evaluate the return value of `IsBlocked()`
2. Assume path is blocked, `FindPath()` will return false due to the blockage placed
3. `IsBlocked()` will return false (side note: this is *backwards!*) and set some variables
4. `yield` will yield, halting further processing of `GetIsBlocked()` (there are no additional lines in this method anyway, so this was pointless).
5. `if (!isBlocked && check)` will evaluate to false
6. `TestLocation()` will return false (and destroy the object)
7. Other `Update()` code will run and eventually (on the next frame) the yield instruction will be re-evaluated.
8. `IsBlocked()` will be evaluated again, this time `IsBlocked()` will return true (because we destroyed the blocking object in #6)
9. `GetIsBlocked()` will complete (but there's no code here to execute).

I cannot guess what weird side effects will occur due to the Update code that hasn't been included.

What you should do instead:

1. Remove all coroutine usage.
2. Correct the return of `IsBlocked()` so that if there *is a block* `return true` (this will essentially turn into `return !FindPath(a, b);` which could be inlined).
3. Change `if (!isBlocked && check)` to `if(IsBlocked())`
4. You do not need the variables `isBlocked` and `check`

Beyond that, your logic is essentially correct:

- Create a blockage
- Check if a path exists
- If it does not, remove the block / prevent placement / whatever

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made these changes but the problem still exists, I think the problem is with my FindPath method which I'll add to my question. I also changed my code in my question to what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by updating my Grid, simple fix as always. :P

Comment: Please share exactly how you solved your problem, so that others with the same question can have a solution, too.